# $ A_{i} \cap A_{j} \neq \emptyset $ Does there exist a set S such that $ S \cap A_{i} \neq \emptyset $ and $ |S| \le 3 $?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

Consider sets $ A_{i} $ which satisfy $ A_{i} \cap A_{j} \neq \emptyset $ for all $1 \leq  i,j \leq n $. Does there exist a set $S$ such that $ S \cap A_{i} \neq \emptyset $ for all $i$ and $ |S| \le 3 $?

I think the claim is false but I have not found a counter example. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take any symmetric matrix $A$ whose elements on the upper triangular part are all distinct. Call $A_i$ the $i-th$ column, meaning that the set $A_i$ contains the numbers in the column. They respect the hypothesis, but every number is at most contained in two distinct $A_i$. As a consequence, if $n>6$, it's impossible to find $S$.

---

As a side comment, if $n\le 6$, then it is true, and you can manually build $S$ taking greedily the elements that belong to the greatest number of $A_i$

Comment: Great solution! How did you come across this so quick?